# How to Pass in Parameters of CTE in view or stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple CTEs and I want to pass in two parameters: one being the date and the other being the CTE table name.

This is for an Oracle database.

The CTEs are like this

```
WITH big_table1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM mini_table1
),
big_table2 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM mini_table2
)
```

The date will be calculated by the select statements in the CTE. I want to do something like select * from &&big_table where &&date = date or any other way (in a view/stored procedure) that would help me pass in dynamically the CTE name and a specific date (like '10-23-2021').

I have tried this and it works: select * from &&big_table where &&date = date. But it needs to be in a stored procedure or view or something that is established I guess. Not really sure why but those are the requirements I need to satisfy.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You cannot access objects dynamically without dynamic SQL. But it requires additional effort to return rows from such SQL. Why do you need dynamic table name and what software will call this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what table names could be involved and if the query from any of the tables return the same number of columns of the same datatype then you could try something like this:

```sql
WITH 
    MINTBL_1 (ID, A_DATE, COL_1, COL_2) AS
        (
            Select 1, To_Date('01.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '1.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('01.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '2.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, To_Date('02.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '3.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, To_Date('03.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '4.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual 
        ),
    MINTBL_2 (ID, A_DATE, COL_1, COL_2) AS
        (
            Select 1, To_Date('26.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '1.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('26.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '2.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual Union All
            Select 8, To_Date('27.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '8.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual Union All
            Select 9, To_Date('28.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '9.something in COL_1', 'something else for COL_2' From Dual 
        )
SELECT  ID "ID", A_DATE "A_DATE", COL_1 "COL_1"
FROM    (     SELECT  CASE WHEN :input_tbl = 'MINTBL_1' THEN 'MINTBL_1' END "SOURCE", ID "ID", A_DATE "A_DATE", COL_1 "COL_1"
              FROM    MINTBL_1 
          UNION ALL
              SELECT  CASE WHEN :input_tbl = 'MINTBL_2' THEN 'MINTBL_2' END "SOURCE", ID "ID", A_DATE "A_DATE", COL_1 "COL_1"
              FROM    MINTBL_2    
        )
WHERE SOURCE Is Not Null And A_DATE = :input_dt
```

if we bound values MINTBL_1 and 01-MAR-23 to bind variables :input_tbl and :input_dt the result should be:

```sql
ID  A_DATE      COL_1
--- ----------- --------------------
1   01-MAR-23   1.something in COL_1
2   01-MAR-23   2.something in COL_1
```

... and for MINTBL_2 as table and 28-FEB-23 as date it will be:

```sql
ID  A_DATE      COL_1
--- ----------- --------------------
9   28-FEB-23   9.something in COL_1
```

Another way to do it could be to use function that returns [REF CURSOR](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor-variables/) ...